# Firebase Read Multiple Objects

Tags: android, firebase

I try to read multiple different objects from the Firebase real time database. It works if I only add one kind of object in the database. If I add another object, the Android app doesn't breaks - but there appears no longer any content.

For example, I have an activity which holds an list with objects of the type Machine. This objects are saved in the Firebase database.

Now I read the objects by this logic:

```
public ArrayList<Machine> readMachines(){
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ChildEventListener childEventListener = mDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            machines.clear();
            if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("Machine")) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = snap.getKey();
                    Machine m = snap.getValue(Machine.class);
                    machines.add(m);
                }
            }
        }

        //OTHER OVERRIDE METHODS
    });
    return machines;
}
```

This works fine at the moment. If i add another object which is a maintenance object, the complete system breaks.

I don't understand this problem, because i check the dataSnapshot key if it fits the "Machine"-key.

Here is the logic of receiving the maintenance objects:

```
public ArrayList<RepairHistory> readMaintenance(final String machineID){
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ChildEventListener childEventListener = mDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            histories.clear();
            if(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("Maintenance")){
                for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String key = snap.getKey();
                    RepairHistory history = snap.getValue(RepairHistory.class);
                    if(history.getS_machineID().equals(machineID)){
                        histories.add(history);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        //OTHER OVERRIDE METHODS
    });
    return histories;
}
```

I save the Data to the Database with this code:

```
public void saveMachine(Machine machine){
    DatabaseReference refDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String keyID  = refDatabase.child("Machine").push().getKey();
    machine.setI_ID(keyID);
    refDatabase.child("Machine").child(keyID).setValue(machine);
}
```

So my question is, why breaks the read logic when im adding a maintenance to the database? My database looks like this if i add a maintenance:
A Maintanance holds the key for a machine, that i know which maintenance is for which machine.

```
    {
  "Machine" : {
    "-KdVxzbMt9nZJUuLQ-Wh" : {
      "i_ID" : "-KdVxzbMt9nZJUuLQ-Wh",
      "i_uID" : "UxCvQy2ifmYh7gkT2gxVGYjwwGg1",
      "s_MachineLocation" : "Maschinen Standort",
      "s_Machinentyp" : "Maschinen Typ",
      "s_Name" : "Arturs Machine"
    }
  },
  "Maintenance" : {
    "-Kdu_CCqdKBH5P_P4Fwd" : {
      "d_repairDate" : {
        "date" : 26,
        "day" : 0,
        "hours" : 11,
        "minutes" : 29,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 53,
        "time" : 1488104993199,
        "timezoneOffset" : -60,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "s_Description" : "Example\n",
      "s_ID" : "-Kdu_CCqdKBH5P_P4Fwd",
      "s_author" : "UxCvQy2ifmYh7gkT2gxVGYjwwGg1",
      "s_machineID" : "-KdVxzbMt9nZJUuLQ-Wh"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the class for RepairHisto:

```
package logical;
```

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class RepairHistory implements Serializable{

```
private Date d_repairDate = new Date();
private String s_ID;
private String s_Description;
private String s_machineID;
private RepairImage r_image;
private String s_author;
private Bitmap image;



public RepairHistory() {
}

public RepairHistory(Date d_repairDate, String s_ID, String s_Description, String s_machineID, RepairImage r_image, String s_author, Bitmap image) {
    this.d_repairDate = d_repairDate;
    this.s_ID = s_ID;
    this.s_Description = s_Description;
    this.s_machineID = s_machineID;
    this.r_image = r_image;
    this.s_author = s_author;
    this.image = image;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getS_ID() {
    return s_ID;
}

public void setS_ID(String s_ID) {
    this.s_ID = s_ID;
}

public String getS_machineID() {
    return s_machineID;
}

public void setS_machineID(String s_machineID) {
    this.s_machineID = s_machineID;
}

public Date getD_repairDate() {
    return d_repairDate;
}

public void setD_repairDate(Date d_repairDate) {
    this.d_repairDate = d_repairDate;
}

public String getS_Description() {
    return s_Description;
}

public void setS_Description(String s_Description) {
    this.s_Description = s_Description;
}

public RepairImage getR_image() {
    return r_image;
}

public void setR_image(RepairImage r_image) {
    this.r_image = r_image;
}

public String getS_author() {
    return s_author;
}

public void setS_author(String s_author) {
    this.s_author = s_author;
}
```

}

Comment: You are adding the ValueEventListener to your database root, is that your intention?

Comment: What is the error you get when the app doesn't work? A full stack trace would be useful.

Comment: @Linxy yes it was my intention. i tried to get the complete elements and after that step i would like to separate the stuff.

Comment: can you post your RepairHistory class and like frank said, the error log

Comment: I don't get an error - the app works in the normal screen but the content doesn't appear anymore